# Rspec Unit Testing : undefined method `email=' for "validations":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

*Update: I changed the test to simply :

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'User' do 
  context "validations" do
    it {should validate_presence_of(:email)}
    it {should validate_uniqueness_of(:email)}
  end
end
```

and am now receiving:

```
*Failures:
  1) User validations should require email to be set
     Failure/Error: it {should validate_presence_of(:email)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email=' for "validations":String
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  2) User validations should require case sensitive unique value for email
     Failure/Error: it {should validate_uniqueness_of(:email)}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `first' for String:Class
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Finished in 0.00248 seconds (files took 1.23 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures
Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5 # User validations should require email to be set
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6 # User validations should require case sensitive unique value for email*
```

---

Hello!! Using rails 4 and Rspec 3, I've written the following test

```
    require 'rails_helper'

     describe 'User' do 

     context 'validations' do
        it { should validate_presence_of :email}
         it "email must be present" do
          expect {
            user = User.new
            user.save
         }.not_to change{ User.count }
       end
     end
  end
```

For the following code:

```
class User <ActiveRecord::Base
include ActiveModel::Model
attr_accessor :email

validates_presence_of :email, message: "Please provide your email address"
validates_uniqueness_of :email

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(email: auth.info.email).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.user_image = auth.info.image
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
    end
end
```

end

And keep receiving the following error:

```
*User
  validations
    should require email to be set (FAILED - 1)
    email must be present
Failures:
  1) User validations should require email to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :email}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email=' for "validations":String
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Finished in 0.03091 seconds (files took 1.22 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure
Failed examples:
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:6 # User validations should require email to be set*
```

Can anyone provide some insight into what I may have wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `describe User` in the beginning of spec.

Explanation:
when you write

```
it {should validate_presence_of(:email)}
```

`should` is called from the subject which by default is describing class. You describe `'User'` - it is not a class.

PS failed spec tells you that method `email=` is called from `"validations"` (it is your context) - it is strange and confuse me. Maybe you should set `subject` directly `subject { User }` (details is [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/subject/explicit-subject))